# Why was this question off-topic?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41436690/7292857) question. It was put on hold:

> **put on hold** as unclear what you're asking [...] 15 hours ago
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please edit your question.

It seems like it has everything it needs:

[image: this is an image description]

So what's the problem? Were the users who closed it wrong, or do I need to improve it in some way?

Comment: I think the "clear problem statement" is hard to understand. It's not clear how the function calls set the conditions.

Comment: Side note [ref*u*ctoring](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) questions are sometimes collect negative votes just for "why on earth would you do that" even if it is not completely valid reason. On other hand ref*a*ctoring questions get better treatment. You may want to present more practical case - the code posted does not look bad in current state for such an abstract example and it is unlikely become better after converting it into single statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is *not* a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's:

- Not verifiable – it won't compile; `condition1`, `do_something()`, etc. are all undefined.
- Not really complete – `// 10 more conditions` doesn't count, and references to a non-existing `condition8` in the question body make it confusing.

Furthermore, the question body is confusing. One of the reasons for this is that you're using dummy `do_stuff()` and `condition8` functions and variables and then partly explain what this is supposed to do in the question body. Why isn't that in the code? And what is `do_anotherthing()` doing? Does that also set a `condition` variable?

I *think* I *may* know what you're looking for, but even after reading the question several times I'm far from *sure*. When in doubt it's better to ask for clarification (by providing comments and putting the question on hold) rather than guess and risk wasting time by providing wrong answer.

This is what the two people who provided a comment meant:

> I'm making some leaps and assumptions. If the current function's ret type is void, shouldn't you be able to just put if (!do_stuff()) return; at the top? If that's not what you're after then please provide a mvce

> It would be be great if you could elaborate the requirement. We cannot help you solely based on assumption from our end

You can always edit your question to make it clearer, after which it can be reopened if it's sufficiently clear.

Comment: I've improved it.

Comment: @Redesign: It's still not a [mcve] though. Why not take the time to actually make it one?