# Is it OK to edit away boilerplate getters and setters from OP's original Java (& equivalent) code?

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

Usually - maybe more experienced - Stack Overflow users remove irrelevant/boilerplate getter/setter code from example code and add a comment like

```
// getters, setters
```

or as I do as a Lombok user by adding following annotations (well, I admit there are not so many others doing this, if any)

```
@Getter @Setter
```

By boilerplate/irrelevant I mean implementations like

```
public Id getId() { return this.id; }
public void setId(Id id) { this.id=id; }
```

so which do nothing else but just assign one field and instead of being packed can be in 4 (or even more if OP loves newlines between code lines) separate lines like

```
public void setId(Id id)
{
   this.id=id;
}
```

IMO this kind of stuff does not help the reader much or might actually make the code even harder to read and so I would like to shorten OP's code by removing those and adding a comment / annotations mentioned above.

**Update** after Glorfindel's answer

I know that many people also copy/paste OP's code and tries to compile it as is to see what fails. I personally tend to copy only the relevant part of the code and add any getter/setter/annotation if needed mostly because the copy&paste and formatting the whole code is sometimes still a bit hard job.

Comment: considering the quality of questions, there would be cases where the issue is in the boilerplate as well. I would avoid this unless I am sure that code is not relevant.

Comment: If you have to pick and chose code from the sample it *may* mean OP did not put any effort to create MCVE...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That might be the case sometime but if the question overall is low quality I'd then rather just flag &| downvote it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A related question was asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340874/4751173). There seem to be two kinds of users who post answers on Stack Overflow:

1. users who try to compile and run the code "inside their head"
2. users who copy and paste the code into their IDE and compile and run it there

Clearly, editing those getters and setters out is beneficial for group 1, but harmful to group 2. The net result is zero, so I would advise *against* editing those out and respect the (probably unconscious) decision of the OP to leave them in.

Of course, *unused* getters and setters can safely be removed, it's not called a *Minimal* Complete and Verifiable Example for nothing.

Comment: For an answer: If there is a lot of code scaffolding, it should be perfectly alright to provide just the fixed problematic  *function* in an answer. So no need to copy the entirety of a question's code. (Yeah... I do realize "its not working, plz supply full code" is practically a boilerplate response.)

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, when I see any sort of code posted in a question where the author has elided actual code with some comment intended to represent that code, and that code is actually needed in order for the code example to be compiled, run, and demonstrate the question author's problem, I stop worrying about answering the question. Life's too short.

The criteria for MCVE is clear, and doesn't include leaving bits out without which the code won't compile. It's true that on occasion a problem in a question can be identified by inspecting the code, but the  *author* of the question has no reason to believe in advance that *their* question is such a one. If they knew enough about the problem to know that, they'd know enough about the problem to fix it themselves.

For even the author of a question, it is unwise to make every person looking to answer their question, re-add parts of the code by hand that were originally in the code in the first place and removed. Many people who otherwise could answer the question will just ignore it, spending their valuable time on some other question that is less likely to waste it.

It would be bad enough for the question author to do this, but for *someone else* to come along and deface the question in this way is completely unreasonable. If the question author does it, they are only hurting themselves. If you do it to them, you are hurting another person (and helping no one…I dispute the notion that having such elements in the code interferes with those who don't want to try to compile the code, or that removing such elements could *help* them).

(As a general rule of thumb for deciding what belongs in a MCVE and what does not: if one of the commonly used IDEs will include the code as part of a standard, blank template for a module, it can probably be left out. Anything that a person would have to type in themselves to get the code to compile and run, needs to be kept in.)

Answer (score 0):

If **unnecessary** getters and setters are present, the code is not a *minimal* example. If the poster is asking for debugging help, they have not provided a MCVE. The question could therefore be closed for that reason, and remain closed until the unnecessary code was edited out. So editing out getters and setters could be the right thing to do, in theory.

However, the presence of that unnecessary code is a clue that the question is a low effort, low quality demand for us to do the poster's debugging for them. The kind of question that will never benefit anyone else ("too localized"). So I'd be inclined to examine the question critically (just to be sure), then downvote, vote to close, and move on. Only in the (sadly) rare cases that the question is inherently good would I edit. I do not recall *any* high quality questions that had large amounts of unnecessary code. They might have had *some* unnecessary code, but it was so little that editing it out would not greatly improve the question.

Comment: Condensed to one word - is this answer effectively: "Maybe"? :p